# fast direct communication between ios and android

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, wifi-direct

at the moment I'm planning to build an cross-plattform app (iOS/android) that streams music from one device to others without internet. Now I'm considering which network technology is best for this use case. By the way I'm sorry I didn't say hello to you, it disappears all the time.

**Existing wifi network:**
I don't wanna use this because I want my app to work everywhere.

**Wifi-Direct:**
Not supported by iOS (tell me if I'm wrong).

**Bluetooth:**
Here I've found kind of conflicting information.

- Bluetooth 2.1 is supported by both iOS and android but iOS has its own protocols and doesn't support the common ones.
- Bluetooth Low Energy provides a data rate that is too slow for high quality music streaming (1Mbit) and is supported by iOS but on the android side version 4.3 is required which suspends about half of all users.
- What I'm not sure about is the "normal" (not LE) usage of Bluetooth 4.0. Does anyone have experience/information about this?

**Creating a wifi hotspot:**
This was my first idea and probably it's the best. But there are several issue:

- Some carriers do not allow hotspots
- It's not possible to create a hotspot without cell reception on the iPhone and some (I don't know which exactly) android devices.
- It's not possible to create a hotspot without cellular data activated on an iPhone; I don't know what about android devices (Nexus 4: no problem, SGS3 mini: cellular data can be switched off after creating the hotspot)
  -> that's a problem for those who don't have an internet unlimited plan or for those who don't want to share their internet connection (as this dissipates the high speed volume) but see the next point for that.
- In order that everyone can use his own cellular data connection the wifi settings can be manually edited on iOS (remove router, DNS and search domains entries). Is there a way to do so on android as well? Is there way to automize this process?
  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173894/can-i-connect-to-wifi-but-still-use-cellular
- Is there any way to create a wifi network programmatically (not just enable the normal wifi hotspot)?

**SDKs/Frameworks** like Open Garden or Alljyon looked promising at the beginning but:

- Firechat (which is made by the Open Garden team) promises that iOS and android devices can chat locally without existing network but actually it didn't work for me with an iPhone 6 and SGS3 mini. However they don't want to publish their SDK. The only information I got is that it works over wifi-direct and bluetooth. If anyone has an idea how this could work, please tell me.
- Alljoyn does not provide direct communications between iOS and android without an existing network. (Tell me if I'm wrong)

**API's:**

- iOS multipeer connectivity does not support android

I hope anyone can help me.

Regards Nils

Comment: How far are the devices from each other? If you considered bluetooth peobably very close to each other.

Comment: Then let the Android device create a hotspot. And let the iPhone connect to this wireless station. Creating a hotspot has nothing to do with a carrier as you will not use the carrier at all. You can even use an Android device without sim card in it.

Comment: On the Nexus 4 that's fine but on the SGS3 mini it only works after having enabled cellular. Do you know a way to avoid this by creating the hotspot programmatically?

Comment: I am facing a similar challenge. Wondering if you managed to overcome it and if so, what technology did you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a TVBOX device with Android, you will need the ethernet cable connected in order to create a hotspot.

Another option that I have done is:
Create a service that runs on iPhone with an interfaz, do whatever you want on that interfaz, then send what ever you need to a webservice, then in Android, just pull that info from another App as a service, or just store it in an internal sqlite.

Good luck